# Powershell, is it possible to replace the password by an hash in the Unlock-BitLocker command?

Tags: powershell, passwords, bitlocker

Related to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/unlock-bitlocker?view=windowsserver2022-ps

```
$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString "fjuksAS1337" -AsPlainText -Force
Unlock-BitLocker -MountPoint "E:" -Password $SecureString
```

That I want to use it in a .ps1 script file ( without ask for the user password ).
The user is only me and it's on my home computer.

My question: Is it possible to replace "fjuksAS1337" by an Hash of "fjuksAS1337" or something less obvious than the literal text password in the script?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: this series is probably what you're after: [How to encrypt credentials & secure passwords](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/#convertto-securestring-and-convertfrom-securestring)

Answer (score 0):

You could save your credentials into an xml file inside some folder where you have set permissions to read/modify only to you like

```
$path = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "OnlyMeCanAccess\bitlocker.xml"
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName $env:USERNAME -Message 'Please enter your credentials'
$cred | Export-CliXml -Path $path -Force
```

Then in your script use it as

```
$path = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "OnlyMeCanAccess\bitlocker.xml"
$cred = Import-Clixml -Path $path
Unlock-BitLocker -MountPoint "E:" -Password $cred.Password
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to keep credentials in script but you can use next scheme:

1. Run PS console and execute next 4 commands.

1.1. Generate *secure key* for encryption (keep it). It is simple key example:

```
[byte[]] $key = (1..32)
```

1.2. Make *secured string* from your password:

```
$SecuredString = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String "fjuksAS1337"
```

1.3. Make *encrypted string* using *secure key*:

```
$EncryptedString = ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $key -SecureString $SecuredString
```

1.4. Print and keep value of `$EncryptedString`:

```
76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345MgB8ADQANgBLAGgAawBKADIANQBSADEAbABBAGEATgBrAHAASgBKAGcAZwBBAFEAPQA9AHwANwA2ADcAMQAzADcAOQBlAGEAZAA2AGMAMAAyADEANwBhAGIAYgBlADQAOABmAGEANABjADgAYQAzAGYAZAA2AGMAYgAxADUAMgA0ADAAMAAxADAAOQA5AGIAYwAxADQAOQAxADEANQAwADAAYQA1AGIAYgA0ADIAZAA5ADMANQA=
```

2. Use encrypted password value in your script (1.4.):

   `$EncryptedString = "76492d1116......ANQA="`
3. Use *secure key* in your script (1.1.):

   `[byte[]] $key = (1..32)`
4. Make *secured string* in script:

   `$SecuredString = ConvertTo-SecureString $EncryptedString -Key $key`
5. Use *secured string* in script:

   `Unlock-BitLocker -MountPoint "E:" -Password $SecuredString`